# Node.js/Mongoose/MongoDb Typescript MapReduce - emit() and Array.sum() methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm trying out a little side project with the MEAN stack and Typescript, and I've seem to run into an issue regarding Typescript not picking up on the typings for the `emit()` and `Array.sum()` methods.

Here's my code below...

```
let options: mongoose.ModelMapReduceOption<IInvoice, any, any> = {
    map: () => {
        emit(this.customer, this.total);
    },
    reduce: (key, values) => {
        return Array.sum(values);
    },
    out: { replace: "map_reduce_customers" },
    verbose: true
};
```

I am using the **typings** package on NPM, and have installed the typings for the **mongodb** as well as **mongoose** packages in my project. There are red squigglies under these two methods, yet the application works just fine when I run.

And yes, it is correctly transpiled to valid JavaScript. I would just like to know if there's a typing definition I'm missing for Typescript to pick up on these two methods?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the emit function like this

```
declare function emit(k, v);
```

and then use non-arrow functions (to be able to use "this" inside the map function)

```
map: function map() {
    emit(this.customer, this.total);
}
```

`Array.sum` does not exist in JS as far as I know. If it's being provided by a library, you may want to install the typings for that library.

Answer (score -1):

> I would just like to know if there's a typing definition I'm missing
>   for Typescript to pick up on these two methods?

Yes, there is. You have to add script references. Add the following to the top of your file (just fix it to the correct paths in your project):

```
///<reference path="../typings/modules/mongodb/index.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../typings/modules/mongoose/index.d.ts" />
```